# Automatic transposition DIV's (CSS)

Tags: css

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f5e5d/1/

```
.item-data {
  width:34px;
  height:34px;
  background-size: 34px auto !important;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display:table-cell;   
}
.test_div {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
.match_details {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

I want to show only 3 pictures in one line. How can I do it?

Now I have displayed all 6 items in 1 line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/f5e5d/4/

```
.item-data {
  width:34px;
  height:34px;
  background-size: 34px auto !important;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
}

.item-data:nth-child(3n+1)
{
    clear: left;
}

.test_div {
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}
```